# Appium inspector for iOS unable to open simulator

Tags: ios, automated-tests, appium, functional-testing, appium-ios

Appium inspector shows the following error while trying to inspect an iOS App

[image]

Comment: Can you post what all capabilities are being set in code as well in the appium server?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working on Mac system and installed appium.dmg then do the following

1. click on Apple Symbol and provide App path(ends with .app).
2. click on force device and chose your device to run  IOS simulator.
3. choose the version IOS simultor  that is platform version
4. Prerequisite is that You should have pre installed simulators.
5. then click on launch....

hope This Helps:)